# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'tuple' and 'bool'

Tags: python, boolean

I got strange error when I tried to use "|" operator in if with tuple.

```
#example
Myset = ((1, 3), (4, 6), (3, 1), (2, 2), (3, 5), (2, 4), (3, 3))
courd = (4,6)
if(courd[0] - 1 ,courd[1] - 1 in d ):
    isSafe = True # work as expected
```

but if I will try something like this:

```
if((courd[0] - 1 ,courd[1] - 1 in d) | 2==2 ): # or something else that involved "|" 
    isSafe = True
```

I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#87>", line 1, in <module>
    if((courd[0] - 1 ,courd[1] - 1 in d )| (2 == 2)):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'tuple' and 'bool'
```

Comment: Well, you have a `tuple` - `(courd[0] - 1 ,courd[1] - 1 in d)` and you're trying to bitwise or it with a `bool` `2==2` (which is `True`) - which isn't supported (what would it mean anyway) - what more is there to be said?

Comment: What do you intend for that to do?

Comment: I think I confused between bitwise or and logical or...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use parens, as needed, like this

```
if((courd[0] - 1, courd[1] - 1) in d):
    pass
```

Now, it will create a tuple `(courd[0] - 1, courd[1] - 1)` and it will check if it is in `d`. In the next case,

```
if((courd[0] - 1, courd[1] - 1 in d) | 2 == 2):
    pass
```

`(courd[0] - 1, courd[1] - 1 in d)` will be evaluated first and that will create a tuple. And then `2 == 2` will be evaluated (since `|` has lower precedence than `==`) to `True`, which is basically a boolean. So, you are effectively doing

```
tuple | boolean
```

That is why you are getting that error.

**Note:** `|` is called bitwise OR in Python. If you meant logical `OR`, you need to write it like this

```
if(((courd[0] - 1, courd[1] - 1) in d) or (2 == 2)):
    pass
```

Now, `(courd[0] - 1, courd[1] - 1)` will be evaluated first to create a tuple and then the tuple will be checked if it exists in `d` (this will return either `True` or `False`, a boolean) and then `(2 == 2)` will be evaluated which returns `True`. Now logical `or` would happily work with two booleans.

Comment: What the different between logical OR and bitwise OR? I know in c# there is a "|" operator that doesn't evaluated the expression and "||" operator that does (or the opposite, I don't remember in this hour). Is logical OR evaluated the expression?

Comment: @OrHalimi [Bitwise Operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators), [Logical Operators](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)